# mat-menu frozen (angular material)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material

I have a `mat-menu` (from angular material) in some other `component`. On selection of an option inside `mat-menu`, I emit the selected values to other `component` and the `component` which receives the emitted value binds that value to the argument of the `pipe`. The `pipe` method used deep copy of lodash. The `mat-menu` is getting frozen and in UI slowness is coming when I switch between the options inside the menu. I have also tried `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify())` for deep copy. My data is nested (four levels). What can be the reason for slowness ?

Comment: Creating a sample plunkr would be helpful. It is difficult to give a solution without code

Comment: Please replicate the error at stackblitz

Answer (score 0):

Angular Material `Mat-Menu` trigger Multiple Change Detection. Even on hover change detection is triggered. As you are performing multilevel chaining for four time. you are using four `*ngFor` Which is creating cascaded change detection.

You can verify same with addition of `trackBy`.

Temparary solution is to divide each for in different component and using `OnPush` `Changedetection` stratergy.

Permanent solution is to fix change detection in angular material `mat-menu` component.

Using `TrackBy` and `onPush` `ChangeDetection` you will get some Performance boost.